# Aimbot for open-source FPS game Assault Cube

Tags: c++, beginner, ai

I am actually quite new to C++, although I have previously programmed in Java. Do you see any ways I can improve readability, maintainability and performance, and make it more object-oriented?

```
/*
    Control + 0 = enable aimbot
*/

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>

const float pi = 3.14159265358979f;

/*
  * I am using int* as if it were the same thing as int**, int***, etc.
  * Another more elegant looking method is to use int as if it were int*, int**, etc
  * but it is more prone to undefined behaviour and I am more likely to get away with the first method.
  * See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256158/dereferencing-a-double-level-pointer-results-in-different-behaviour-from-derefer
*/
int* getClosestPointer(int** basePointer, int offsets[], int levels) {
    for (int i = 0; i < levels; i++) {
        basePointer = (int**) (*basePointer + offsets[i] / sizeof(int));
    }
    return (int*) basePointer;
}

/*
  [Player base] = A
  [A + 34] = X
  [A + 38] = Y
  [A + 3C] = Z
  [A + 40] = Crosshair X
  [A + 44] = Crosshair Y
  [A + F4] = HP
  [A + 154] = Grenades
*/
int playerBaseXOffsets[] = { 0x34 };
int playerBaseYOffsets[] = { 0x38 };
int playerBaseZOffsets[] = { 0x3C };
int playerBaseCXOffsets[] = { 0x40 };
int playerBaseCYOffsets[] = { 0x44 };
int playerBaseHPOffsets[] = { 0xF4 };
int playerBaseAmmoOffsets[] = { 0x368, 0x14, 0 };
int playerBaseGrenadesOffsets[] = { 0x154 };

typedef struct Player {
    int** basePointer;
    float* xPointer;
    float* yPointer;
    float* zPointer;
    float* cXPointer;
    float* cYPointer;
    int* hpPointer;
    int* ammoPointer;
    int* grenadesPointer;

    Player() {
    }

    Player(int** basePtr) {
        basePointer = basePtr;
        xPointer = (float*) getClosestPointer(basePointer, playerBaseXOffsets, sizeof(playerBaseXOffsets) / sizeof(playerBaseXOffsets[0]));
        yPointer = (float*) getClosestPointer(basePointer, playerBaseYOffsets, sizeof(playerBaseYOffsets) / sizeof(playerBaseYOffsets[0]));
        zPointer = (float*) getClosestPointer(basePointer, playerBaseZOffsets, sizeof(playerBaseZOffsets) / sizeof(playerBaseZOffsets[0]));
        cXPointer = (float*) getClosestPointer(basePointer, playerBaseCXOffsets, sizeof(playerBaseCXOffsets) / sizeof(playerBaseCXOffsets[0]));
        cYPointer = (float*) getClosestPointer(basePointer, playerBaseCYOffsets, sizeof(playerBaseCYOffsets) / sizeof(playerBaseCYOffsets[0]));
        hpPointer = getClosestPointer(basePointer, playerBaseHPOffsets, sizeof(playerBaseHPOffsets) / sizeof(playerBaseHPOffsets[0]));
        ammoPointer = getClosestPointer(basePointer, playerBaseAmmoOffsets, sizeof(playerBaseAmmoOffsets) / sizeof(playerBaseAmmoOffsets[0]));
        grenadesPointer = getClosestPointer(basePointer, playerBaseGrenadesOffsets, sizeof(playerBaseGrenadesOffsets) / sizeof(playerBaseGrenadesOffsets[0]));
    }
} Player;

Player players[32] = { };

/* Pythagorean's theorem (flavour for 3D) */
float getDistanceBetween(Player one, Player two) {
    return sqrt(
        (*(one.xPointer)-*(two.xPointer))*(*(one.xPointer)-*(two.xPointer))
        + (*(one.yPointer)-*(two.yPointer))*(*(one.yPointer)-*(two.yPointer))
        + (*(one.zPointer)-*(two.zPointer))*(*(one.zPointer)-*(two.zPointer))
        );
}

int getNumberOfPlayers() {
    return *((int*) ((UINT) GetModuleHandleW(0) + 0xE4E10));
}

Player* getClosestTarget() {
    float smallestDistance;
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < getNumberOfPlayers(); i++) {
        if (*(players[i].hpPointer) > 0) {
            float tempDistance = getDistanceBetween(players[0], players[i]);
            if (index == -1 || tempDistance < smallestDistance) {
                smallestDistance = tempDistance;
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }
    if (index == -1) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return &players[index];
    }
}

/* Gets the crosshair horizontal angle in degrees. */
float getCX(Player me, Player target) {
    float deltaX = *(target.xPointer) - *(me.xPointer);
    float deltaY = *(me.yPointer) - *(target.yPointer);
    if (*(target.xPointer) > *(me.xPointer) && *(target.yPointer) < *(me.yPointer)) {
        return atanf(deltaX/deltaY) * 180.0f / pi;
    } else if(*(target.xPointer) > *(me.xPointer) && *(target.yPointer) > *(me.yPointer)) {
        return atanf(deltaX/deltaY) * 180.0f / pi + 180.0f;
    } else if(*(target.xPointer) < *(me.xPointer) && *(target.yPointer) > *(me.yPointer)) {
        return atanf(deltaX/deltaY) * 180.0f / pi - 180.0f;
    } else {
        return atanf(deltaX/deltaY) * 180.0f / pi + 360.0f;
    }
}

/* Gets the crosshair vertical angle in degrees. */
float getCY(Player me, Player target) {
    float deltaZ = *(target.zPointer) - *(me.zPointer);
    float dist = getDistanceBetween(me, target);
    return asinf(deltaZ/dist) * 180.0f / pi;
}

int main() {
    bool aimbotEnabled = false;
    Player* closestTargetPointer = NULL;

    // [Base + DF73C] = Player 1 base
    players[0] = Player((int**) ((UINT) GetModuleHandleW(0) + 0xDF73C));
    int** extraPlayersBase = *((int***) ((UINT) GetModuleHandleW(0) + 0xE5F00));

    while (true) {
        // [Base + E5F00] = A
        // [A + 0,4,8...] = Player 2/3/4... base
        for (int i = 0; i < getNumberOfPlayers() - 1; i++) {
            players[i + 1] = Player(extraPlayersBase + i * 4 / sizeof(int*));
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL) && GetAsyncKeyState('0')) {
            aimbotEnabled = !aimbotEnabled;
            Sleep(500);
        }

        if (aimbotEnabled) {
            closestTargetPointer = getClosestTarget();

            if (closestTargetPointer != NULL) {
                *(players[0].cXPointer) = getCX(players[0], *closestTargetPointer);
                *(players[0].cYPointer) = getCY(players[0], *closestTargetPointer);
            }
        }

        Sleep(10);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI Main(LPVOID lpParam) {
    main();
    return S_OK;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hModule);
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &Main, NULL, 0, NULL);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: At `getCX` there is some pieces of repeated code. I think it's best to eliminate it, maybe use another function. Otherwise looks good for me - but I'm not good in C and/or WinAPI.

Answer (score 5):

**Your C++ is very C-like.** I would start by taking advantage of C++:

- You will almost always want to use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

  For example:

  ```
  std::vector<Player> players;
  players.reserve(32);
  ```

  This will create a vector large enough to hold 32 `Player`s. If you ever need room for more, the vector will grow automatically when you add more players. By accessing elements using `players.at(index)`, you will get range-checking.

  To get the number of elements in a `vector`, you can use `players.size()` instead of using the `sizeof` array division hack.
- Your `struct` typedef-ing is a common idiom in C, because in C you need to qualify `struct` identifiers with `struct` in order to use them: `void foo(struct Bacon* bacon)`. In C++ you don't have to do this. I would therefore change your definition of `Player` to:

  ```
  class Player {
  public:
      // contents
  };
  ```
- The variables in `Player` should normally be encapsulated. This means they should be defined in the `private` section of the class (above `public:`). If you need access to the variables from other functions or classes, then you can provide accessor functions:

  ```
  class Player {
      int** basePointer;
  public:
      int** getBasePointer() const { return basePointer; }
  };
  ```
- If you really want to use your `struct` as [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Data_Structures), I recommend making the members `const` and making a copy every time your need to. This isn't a *must*, but reduces the chances of unintentional changes.
- In short, your class (a `struct` is a class) could and probably should be designed like a *class*, and not like POD.
- Like @Jamal points out, you can use `enum` for your offsets:

  ```
  enum Offsets { playerBaseXOffset = 0x34, playerBaseYOffset = 0x38 /* ... */ };
  ```

  If you are expecting to have more offsets of a kind later, use a `std::vector` instead:

  ```
  std::vector<std::size_t> playerBaseXOffsets{ 0x34 }; // C++11 syntax.
  ```

  > **Note the `{` and `}` in the last example. *Using* `(` *and* `)` *instead compiles, but means something entirely different!*** (It will default-construct 0x34 = 52 objects.)
- I'm not sure if all your pointer fiddling is really necessary. If it's not, I recommend you avoid it. It is error prone, and some of the potential errors can be really hard to find. You risk forgetting to dereference a pointer if you're lucky; you get undefined behavior from [violating the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) if you're not.
- Use symbolic, rather than literal, constants. For example:

  ```
  const std::size_t player_one_base_offset = 0xDF73C;
  players[0] = Player((int**) ((UINT) GetModuleHandleW(0) + player_one_base_offset));
  ```

  I'm sure you agree `player_one_base_offset` is much more readable and understandable than `0xDF73C`.
- I would normally recommend C++-style `static_cast<type>(object)` instead of your C-style `(type)object` casting, but in your case I think it would just reduce readability even more without giving much benefit.

And finally, not directly code related: It's either *Pythagoras' theorem*, or the *Pythagorean theorem*.

Comment: +1.  I did forgot to mention `std::vector` here (even after seeing many arrays), but I got the `enum`s.

Comment: @Jamal In all fairness, you did recommend using the STL. I was just a little more concrete.

Comment: True.  Although, when looking at the Player array, I was more concerned about it being in a better place (`main()` or a Game class).  I am quite lost in this design, but it'd be great to see it become more C++-like.

Comment: By the way, what do you think about the `"stdafx.h"` in the code?  I know it indicates a pre-compiled header under Visual C++ (I would know), but I'm not sure if it's even necessary.

Comment: @Jamal In this case it's necessary for the WinAPI calls. For a program that by nature is platform-restricted like this, I see no harm in it.

Comment: I see.  I tend to avoid it since it seems tacky and unnecessary (at least right now).

Answer (score 4):

- This is C++, not C, so use `<cmath>` instead of `<math.h>`.
- This would look and function better with more `class`es, especially since it's a game.  For instance, `Player` can become a class instead of a `struct` so that it can be kept `private`.  There should also be a `Game` class to keep a collection of Players and handle the gameplay.  You will simply initiate the game in `main()` by creating a Game object.  Note that `main()` should not have access to anything within the game beyond the ability to start it.
- I agree with @Lstor about making an `std::vector` of `Player`s.  This will also allow you to access each Player using the container's iterators.  If you have C++11, you have two options, depending on whether or not your compiler supports **range-based for-loops**:

  *If it does...*

  ```
  for (auto const& player : players)
  {
      std::cout << player;
  }
  ```

  *If it does not...*

  ```
  for (auto iter = players.cbegin(); iter != players.cend(); ++iter)
  {
      std::cout << *iter;
  }
  ```

  In your game, you would be operating on this vector inside the Game class only.  This is important because it shouldn't be exposed through the interface.  You're free to define a display function (or overload `operator<<`), **but you mustn't break encapsulation**.
- The parameters in `getCX()` and `getCY()` should be const-refs since they're not modified:

  ```
  float getCX(Player const& me, Player const& target) {}
  float getCY(Player const& me, Player const& target) {}
  ```
- The `playerBaseOffset`s look like they should be `const`.  I'd also prefer something more concise than single arrays, such as an `enum`.  It could also be put into a `namespace` to avoid name collisions.
- The STL *should* especially be utilized to take advantage of smart pointers in place of raw pointers (the latter is more C-like).  Beyond that, using the STL as much as possible will clean up your code considerably.  As for pointers in general, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` if you're using C++11.
- Regarding @Lstor's answer, include `<cstddef>` in order to use `std::size_t`.

Comment: A `struct` is a class where default access is `public` instead of `private`.

Comment: @Lstor: Yeah, I wasn't clear enough.  I'll fix it.

Comment: `for (auto const& player : players) { std::cout << player; }` :-)

Comment: @Lstor: I'll put that as another option (with specifics). ;-)

Comment: [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), [msvc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx), [icc](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler) and [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) have [all supported range-based `for` loops](http://cpprocks.com/c11-compiler-support-shootout-visual-studio-gcc-clang-intel/) for a while.

Comment: @Lstor: Right.  Again, I still have MSVC2010, which doesn't support it.  I'm still trying to determine the best way to upgrade compilers (preferably gcc).